# Would transaction work across multiple DB in the same SQL server? If so, is this a Distributed transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012

Would transaction work across multiple DB in the same SQL server?
If so, is this a Distributed transaction? or would basic `BEGIN TRANSACTION` work?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A transaction across multiple DBs in the same instance is a local transaction. BEGIN TRANSACTION will work just fine.

Comment: is MSDTC service required for this kind of transaction? Will this transaction be a distributed transaciton?

Comment: @Entrodus DTC is not involved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976740/distributed-database-transaction-vs-cross-database-transaction

Comment: A small note from official documentation : A transaction within a single instance of the Database Engine that spans two or more databases is actually a distributed transaction. The instance manages the distributed transaction internally; to the user, it operates as a local >transaction.'  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191440(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 12):

Just tested it. `BEGIN TRANSACTION` works as expected across two databases on the same server.

Answer (score -3):

SQL Server documention is clear about how to start a distributed transaction.

[BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188386.aspx)

Comment: Distributed transaction is only required for databases in different instances, linked through linked servers. If both databases are in the same Sql Server instance, then BEGIN TRANSACTION will suffice.