# Distributed database transaction vs cross database transaction

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

What's the different between Distributed database transaction and cross database transaction in SQL Server.

I know that Distribute database transaction is a transaction between multiple database and can use by following query :

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Cross database transaction occurs between 2 or more databases on the ***same*** server. It does not require the involvement of a DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator)

A Distributed database transaction occurs between 2 or more databases hosted on multiple servers.  DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) services are required on each participating server.