# sql transaction to many databases

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Is it possible in sql to have one transaction which will work with many databases? I didnt find answer surfing the net(((

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479201/would-transaction-work-across-multiple-db-in-the-same-sql-server-if-so-is-this

Comment: I meant different SQL servers)))

Comment: than Distributed Transactions could help you http://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/02/27/sql-server-distributed-transactions.aspx